# Quickly edit / change hosts file on Windows

Tags: windows, hosts, hosts-file

I routinely need to add  / remove / update hosts on a Windows 7 machine to add links to staging / test servers.

On Mac I can use [ghosts](https://github.com/bjeanes/ghost) with the syntax

> ghost add staging-server.local 67.207.136.164

Is there a similar command I can use on Windows to achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two (well, three really) ways you can do it.

**GUI** (using notepad, or whatever editor)

Right click on your favourite editor, ensure you `Run as administrator` (escalate them privileges), goto `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\HOSTS` and then add, edit to your heart's content.

Running without privileges will get you an *Access Denied* error when you try to save, which is thanks to some Windows security they put up some time ago.

**cmd** (surprisingly, it has a use sometimes)

Type `cmd` into your startbar, right click and `Run as Administrator`, then you can just type `echo ipaddress    site.com >> c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\HOSTS`

**Alternate GUI** (What I would advocate)

[Hostsman](http://www.abelhadigital.com/hostsman) is a nice little program which gives you a GUI you can manage your HOSTS on. I don't know about any other programs, but this seems to work perfectly find for what is needed.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, the the file you need to edit must be edited as Administrator, and the path is c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts. It can be edited with Notepad or [vim](http://chocolatey.org/packages/vim) or whatever you prefer.

[Hosts File Editor](https://hostsfileeditor.codeplex.com/) is a nice open source and free GUI for managing the hosts file.

Comment: 1 Up for Hosts File Editor!